# how to construct a proper nested XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

[image: THIS is my query]

[image: THIS is MY RESULT]

I want the DECLARATION tag to close behind the ENCOURS and before TCN how to do this please?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2029983)

Comment: i have à validation problem !

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal, reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stooped down and typed a DDL and sample data population for you (instead of you).

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @ENTETE TABLE (CIB_DECLARANT INT, Type_Fischier VARCHAR(30), numero_de_remise INT, date_declaration DATE);
INSERT INTO @ENTETE (CIB_DECLARANT, Type_Fischier, numero_de_remise, date_declaration) 
VALUES (10057, 'DECLARATION_TCN', 1, '2019-12-03');

DECLARE @DECLARATION TABLE (siren_emetteur INT);
INSERT INTO @DECLARATION (siren_emetteur) 
VALUES (12345);

DECLARE @CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE TABLE (type_mouvement CHAR(1), code_isin VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE (type_mouvement, code_isin)
VALUES ('C', 'fr12345');

DECLARE @MOUVEMENT_TITRE TABLE (type_mouvement CHAR(1), code_isin VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @MOUVEMENT_TITRE (type_mouvement, code_isin)
VALUES ('C', 'fr400016');

DECLARE @ENCOURS TABLE (code_devise CHAR(3), montant_encours INT);
INSERT INTO @ENCOURS (code_devise, montant_encours)
VALUES ('EUR', 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @ENTETE
    FOR XML PATH('ENTETE'), TYPE
    )
    , (
    SELECT *
        , (
        SELECT *
        FROM @CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE
        FOR XML PATH('CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE'), TYPE
        )
        , (
        SELECT *
        FROM @MOUVEMENT_TITRE
        FOR XML PATH('MOUVEMENT_TITRE'), TYPE
        )
        , (
        SELECT *
        FROM @ENCOURS
        FOR XML PATH('ENCOURS'), TYPE
        )
    FROM @DECLARATION
    FOR XML PATH('DECLARATION'), TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('TCN');
```

> Output

```
<TCN>
  <ENTETE>
    <CIB_DECLARANT>10057</CIB_DECLARANT>
    <Type_Fischier>DECLARATION_TCN</Type_Fischier>
    <numero_de_remise>1</numero_de_remise>
    <date_declaration>2019-12-03</date_declaration>
  </ENTETE>
  <DECLARATION>
    <siren_emetteur>12345</siren_emetteur>
    <CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE>
      <type_mouvement>C</type_mouvement>
      <code_isin>fr12345</code_isin>
    </CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE>
    <MOUVEMENT_TITRE>
      <type_mouvement>C</type_mouvement>
      <code_isin>fr400016</code_isin>
    </MOUVEMENT_TITRE>
    <ENCOURS>
      <code_devise>EUR</code_devise>
      <montant_encours>0</montant_encours>
    </ENCOURS>
  </DECLARATION>
</TCN>
```